# Testing a shell script with Travis CI (POSIX)

Tags: shell, travis-ci

I am testing a shell script on Travis CI with

```
language: bash
```

and it is working without any problem. I would like to test with different bash versions (3 or 4) or maybe also other shells. For example `/bin/sh` or dash.

I did not find bash in the l[ist of supported languages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/).

Which are the supported shells? And versions?

Comment: About the close request: I am not asking a recommendation. I am asking about a badly documented feature of a development tool. As `bash` is working and is not in the documentation, I am wandering what is supported.

Comment: There's one and only Bash per system, and you won't get more OOTB. However, an issue similar to [this one](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5175) pops up often (and if you dig deep enough, you'll find the original one), so your best bet as of now is to use, sadly, undocumented, `language: generic`.